# How can i display image by using div tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

net , I want to display an image by using div tag . I am using following div to do this . My div is

`<div style="background: transparent url('arrow_left.png') no-repeat center center; width:32px; height: 32px;"></div>`

Comment: and the problem you are having ?

Comment: we can't help you when in your question isn't real question:(

Comment: I am not getting image , when i use above tag .

Comment: I'm willing to bet your image is not in same folder as your markup and as such the relative link won't work. Have you tried `'/arrow_left.png'` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This one has worked for me :

```
 <div style="background: transparent  url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5') no-repeat  top left; width:132px; height: 132px;"></div>
```

[->](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

http://jsbin.com/upudow/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

1. the image exists (try using the normal `<img>`)
2. check that the div has actually width and height, you can use FireBug for this or the native browser debugging tools.
3. are you using this Div in some User Control? check good the path issues